# Mac OS X Symbol in filename priority

Tags: finder, window, filenames

Not sure if this feature was in OS9 and under or ever made it to X or was in 9, or what.. but it used to be that if a user started a filename with a '!', then it would be listed first in Finder windows sorting the files alphabetically.. and if the filename started it with a '&' it would be at the bottom of an alphabetical list in Finder windows...

the '!' still puts file first, but is there a symbol or non-english letter or something to start filenames with to send them to the bottom of a Finder Window list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you restrict filenames to ASCII then you can use `~`; if you allow for Unicode it is a bit trickier, because it goes on a rather looong ways (Character Map shows existence of a block at U+100000, but the character display area stops at U+2FFFF).  Practically, you could probably get away with U+FFFD (the glyph substitution character) if you don't care about the higher planes... but I suggest you pop open Character Map to decide where you're cutting things off.  (Also make sure Lucida Grande has a glyph at/near your cutoff!  And Monaco if you also work from Terminal.)

Comment: Have you tested this? The Unicode standard has sorting rules that don't follow the numeric values of the code points. Dunno if Finder honors those rules or not.

Comment: oh I think I am looking for an even easier solution than this.. how can I type the symbol that is a replacement for the old '&'.. is it ™ or £ or maybe † ?

Answer (score 1):

filenames starting with a 'Ω' (altZ) are sent to the bottom of a finder windows list